# Setting currentTime on html5 video throws "PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: video decode error" on windows Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, windows, google-chrome, html5-video

Seeking the video (changing its currentTime by setting it explicitly rather than using the play function) may cause it to throw

```
MediaError {code: 3, message: "PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: video decode error"}
```

It only occurs on Chrome and on Windows.

I managed to fix by changing turn it off Chrome's "use hardware acceleration when available" option under settings and then resetting Chrome.

However I'd like some permanent solution that doesn't involve asking the user to set browser settings.

My server is returning 206 as this answer specifies https://stackoverflow.com/a/36101965/1351652
I am waiting for the load events, video works fine for playing and sometimes skipping works. 
It seems the error is more frequent if I try to seek repetedly, very fast. I do have a listener that doesn't let the client seek the video if the previous call to setCurrentTime didn't finish (seeked event)

On the server side I'm using node + express. My videos are in a static folder and I serve them using

```
app.use('/videos',validateToken,express.static('videos'))
```

validateToken is checking for a JWT token in the url