# html5 seek issue in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, jetty

An application that plays back video stream in a browser pop up window does not allow seeking in chrome but works in firefox and edge.
This issue has been brought up a few times here and I found that the following response more fits my situation:

[html 5 seek issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751736/seeking-in-html5-video-with-chrome)

Here the OP mentions the relation of the jetty server and its lack of support for http code 206 partial content retrieval. My question is whether a simple upgrade to the latest jetty version will fix this? Or has someone found a workaround to resolve this as we are restricted to the use of chrome for this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved my situation by ensuring the response had the proper range headers and that the actual content-length was specified for playback.

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 0-1025/905357
Content-Length: 905357
```

EDIT: this works so far for short videos and audio files but fails with jetty.EofException on large files