# Make HTML5 video start at specified currentTime in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I want to let the user click a button to loop a HTML5 video at a specified start time, which is not 0, and a specified end time, which is not the end of the whole video.

I don't want to force the video to be a certain length permanently. I want to eventually give the user multiple buttons to let them loop over different intervals of the video.

It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. No errors are thrown but it seems that Chrome doesn't register my `currentTime` assignments. It will begin at 0, not the specified start time, but it will end at the specified end time. It loops. The problem is just the start time.

SSCCE:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <video src="./example.mp4" width="480" controls></video>
    <div><button id="storyText">Loop</button></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var timeStamp = [7, 11];

    $('button').click(function() {
        playVideoInterval(timeStamp[0], timeStamp[1]);
    });

    function playVideoInterval(start, end) {
        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', loop);
        video.currentTime = start;
        document.body.addEventListener('click', endLoop, true);
        video.play();

        function loop() {
            if (this.currentTime >= end) {
                video.currentTime = start;
                video.play();
            }
        }

        function endLoop() {
            video.pause();
            document.body.removeEventListener('click', endLoop);
            video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', loop);
        }
    }    
});
```

EDIT: I have also attempted to enclose the code in my document.ready function in an event listener that listens for `canplay` event or `loadedmetadata` event. Neither help.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var timeStamp = [7, 11];

    video.addEventListener('canplay', execute);
    function execute() {
        video.removeEventListener('canplay', execute);
        $('button').click(function() {
            playVideoInterval(timeStamp[0], timeStamp[1]);
        });

        function playVideoInterval(start, end) {
            video.addEventListener('timeupdate', loop);
            video.currentTime = start;
            document.body.addEventListener('click', endLoop, true);
            video.play();

            function loop() {
                if (this.currentTime >= end) {
                    video.currentTime = start;
                    video.play();
                }
            }

            function endLoop() {
                video.pause();
                document.body.removeEventListener('click', endLoop);
                video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', loop);
            }
        }    
    }
});
```

EDIT: I'm using a server to serve it at localhost and this is where it is having problems. If I open the static page direct in the web browser, it is fine.

Comment: If you want to loop a part of the video from start time to end time, i tried your code and it's working in chrome v69.0.3497.100. Which version are you using ?

Comment: 69.0.3497.100 too -- i don't want to loop from 0 -- did yours loop from the specified time of 7 seconds and end at 11 seconds? @ElJackiste

Comment: Yes i'm looping from anytime : http://jsfiddle.net/zpsho125
Your video end time is less or equal than the total time of the video ?

Comment: less than, your video is shorter than mine, but i can see that it works if i change the end time on your jsfiddle. wonder if its because of jsfiddle, or because the video is served on the internet... idk :/

Comment: interesting. i just used your video file link in my local environment and it worked. seems like it is a problem with uploading the html5 video. maybe chrome needs it all in the browser before it'll let me set currentTime? so weird. my event listeners should have worked?

Comment: I just tried in my local environment with a a local video (of 30 minutes) and it works too.

Comment: Exact same code?

Comment: Yeah, same code. Your video is stored on internet or your local environment ?

Comment: My local environment. I’m using python httpserver to serve cuz I have ajax requests in other parts of my site. Just tried my sscce and it works locally with no server. Maybe it is the server.

Comment: In fact doesn't seems to change anything to me. I just tried with few long video stored on internet or on my local computer and it works.

Comment: Try to create an index.html on your desktop and to copy paste the jsfiddle code ?

Comment: Yeah it works completely locally but if i serve on localhost it doesn’t listen to currentTime

Comment: this answers my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751736/seeking-in-html5-video-with-chrome thanks for your time and help in narrowing this down!

Comment: I was going to say, i tried with wamp and then with a node.js server and it works too :p Glad you find out.