# Angular 7 : set video currentTime is always 0

Tags: html, angular, angular7, webapi

I want to control my video with a **range input**, the problem is when I set video.currentTime to 2 (for example) , it still stucking always on 0, and the value is never changed.

here is my **angular 7** code:

**index.component.html**

```
<video *ngIf="product?.video"
             id="myVideo"
             width="100%"
             height="100%"
             #myVideo
             (loadedmetadata)="onMetadata($event, myVideo)"
             (loadeddata)="pauseVideo(myVideo)"
      >
        <source [src]="serverUrl+product.video.file" type="video/mp4">
        Votre navigateur ne supporte pas le plugin des vidéos.
      </video>
...
...
<input class="range-slider__range" #slider type="range" value="0" min="0" step="1" [max]="maxDuration"
                     (input)="updateVideo(slider.value)"
              >
```

**index.component.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('myVideo') my3DVideo: ElementRef;
  maxDuration = 0;
..
..
pauseVideo(myVideo) {
      console.log("data loaded.");
      myVideo.currentTime = 3; // i used this line to force juming to second 3 but it still always 0
      myVideo.pause();
      console.log(myVideo.currentTime);
  }

  updateVideo(value: any) {
      console.log("sliding..");
      const video = this.my3DVideo.nativeElement;// as HTMLVideoElement;
      video.currentTime = value; // this value is never changes too and it still always 0 
  }
  onMetadata($event, my3DVideo) {
    this.maxDuration = my3DVideo.duration;
  }
```

**In addition,** i tried to replace the url with an available distant mp4 video, it worked, but in localmachine it did not working.
**another try,** is  that I tried this code on firefox, it worked like a charm, but in chrome it does not .

I searched a lot about this topic but i still did not find any solution, i hope you can help me.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who suffers about chrome seeking html5 video bug, here is my solution :
in laravel (server side):

```
/**
     * Get video BLOB format
     *
     */
    public function getVideoBlob(){
        $file_name = 'video.mp4';
        $file_contents = \Storage::disk('public')->get($videoPath);
        return response($file_contents)
            ->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache private')
            ->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
            ->header('Content-Type', 'video/mp4')
            ->header('Content-length', strlen($file_contents))
            ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $file_name)
            ->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
    }
```

in the client side just follow this link for how to request a [BLOB files from Angular](https://medium.com/techinpieces/blobs-with-http-post-and-angular-5-a-short-story-993084811af4).

Answer (score 0):

Although counterintuitive, getting a value from an `<input type="range">` will give you back a string, like "42", instead of a number.

You can easily convert it to a number by adding a plus sign in front of it, in this line:

instead of

```
video.currentTime = value
```

try

```
video.currentTime = +value // this will convert the string to a number
```

Comment: I tried it from the begining but, it still not working, the problem is clear that chrome has a specific processing comparing to firefox .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I saw this solution :
[Seeking in HTML5 video with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751736/seeking-in-html5-video-with-chrome)

but i still could not be able to configure that with laravel and angular ..